# How do I make Wordpress and an ASP.NET MVC 2webapp appear as one app to the end user?

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I want to use Wordpress as a CMS for our domains content pages, and also provide links to and from CMS and our service which is an asp.net MVC 2 app, and I would really appreciate some guidance on this subject:

The first approach that comes to my mind is to bind my wordpress site to "thedomain.com" and then bind the service to "service.thedomain.com", and just have them point to the different websites in IIS. In my opinion it does not provide a seamless experience since we are effectively moving from one domain to another when navigating between MVC and wordpress.

How would you solve the task of making a wordpress app and an MVC app appear to be one?

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker came up with an interesting solution to a similar issue and to solve it he wrote a theme in WP that shows all front-end results in JSON. Then, he used ajax/js to pull in content by sending a link to the WP server and pulling back in the JSON-formatted results. I have been meaning write up a blog post about it but the concept should get you started.

Basically, a main-server-page loads all the HTML then hits the wp-server and pulls in the necessary content. The main issue with doing it this way was the page would be empty if the user disabled JS or something else went wrong, but we never had that issue on a lightly-used server.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Even though it sounds like a smart solution Its not really a solution that will work in my scenario.